# Transform an tab of key values into an array of key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I would like to transform an tab array of key values into an array of key values

```
     rates.map(rate => {
       return {
         [rate]: account.vent.filter(v => v.rate === rate)[0]
           ?.vat,
       }
     })


(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {10: 500}
1: {20: 630}
2: {5: undefined}
3: {19.6: undefined}
4: {1: undefined}
```

I have this in my console I would like something more like:

```
{
  10: 500
  20: 630
  5: undefined
  19.6: undefined
  1: undefined
}
```

Comment: it is sounds more as a `groupBy` rather than `map`

Comment: What you want is an object, not an array. Please revisit your question title and text, what you're asking doesn't make any sense. (transform X into X)

Comment: Use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `.filter()[0]`. If you want an object, look into mapping `rates` to an array of inner arrays `[key, value]` instead of objects and pass that mapped array to [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) instead. If you need your mapped array for some other reason, and just want to convert your existing data, you can use `const res = Object.assign({}, ...mappedData);`

Comment: It would help if you added your input data to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this and your problems will be solved

```
.reduce(function(p,c){
    return {...p,...c};
},{})
```

Your code will look like this after adding the above code

```
rates.map(rate => {
       return {
         [rate]: account.vent.filter(v => v.rate === rate)[0]
           ?.vat,
       }
     })
.reduce(function(p,c){
    return {...p,...c};
},{})
```

Comment: the solution works but the output table is sorted alphabetically

Comment: no need to do both a `map` and `reduce`. The `map` code could be incorporated in the `reduce` so that it is done with a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a more appropriate method to use for your case, since you want to create an object out of an array.

something like

```
 rates.reduce((ratesObj, rate) => {
   ratesObj[rate] = account.vent.find(v => v.rate === rate)?.vat;
   return ratesObj;
 }, {})
```

Comment: If there were dupelicate rates the latest one will be kept in the resulting object. If one wanted to retain the first occurrence, one may explore using: `ratesObj[rate] ??= account.vent.find(v => v.rate === rate)?.vat;`

Comment: @jsN00b that is true, although the OP has the same issue, and does not mention wanting to handle it in a special way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array.reduce((acc, item)=>{
    return {...acc, ...item}
},{})
```

Reduce Method:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

A good video on reduce method:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfieE2G3bfg

Comment: How does this solve the problem? What is `reduce`? Have you explained it or added links to documentation?